# What means 'bin' in '$ bin/rails?'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bash

I'm trying to follow along the "Getting Started with Engines" Rails Guide's tutorial and found this:

```
$ bin/rails plugin new blorgh --mountable
```

When I type this on my terminal, I get:

```
bash: bin/rails: No such file or directory
```

When I try just  `$ rails` it works OK.

I've been using the command line for a couple of months, and Rails as well. I know the $ sign but I'm confused about the meaning of the "bin" after that. I'm used to type "Rails" right after $, but this tutorial says that use "bin" ...

What does `bin/` mean?

Comment: The command prompt and the folder the executable is in. How old is this tutorial?

Comment: in other words, the unix equivalent of `C:\>`

Comment: `$` at the start of the line means nothing as far as what you type in. Ignore it and type in what follows it. Whoever provided the example should have cleaned that garbage out because that sort of stuff confuses people.

Comment: @theTinMan It's traditionally used in unix tutorials to indicate that you're on the command line and are operating as a normal user rather than root (#). It also helps to differentiate command output from input. I imagine it's easy for someone to assume that if you're using Rails on Unix you're probably familiar enough with the shell to know what it means.

Comment: I know that, I've been doing this a loooong time, however more and more people are starting to program with absolutely no command-line, let alone Linux, experience. The subtlety of `$` vs `#` means little to them and only confuses their attempts to accomplish things.

Comment: @rovitulli It may help to read http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html first: this has details on the conventions used in the RailsGuides, including what the `$` means. @theTinMan The subtlety of $ and # meant little to me at one point, and probably confused me 25 years ago, but that's what learning's all about, isn't it?

Comment: @MattGibson thanks. I've been using the command line for a couple of months, and Rails as well. I know the $ sign but I'm confused about the meaning of the "bin" after that. I'm used to type "Rail" right after $, but this tutorial says that use "bin" is the right way...

Comment: Typing bin/rails everytime is boring, add to your `.profile`: `alias rails='bin/rails'`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### tl;dr

Run `bundle install --binstubs` and it'll work. You only have to do it once and Bundler will remember that you asked for it (for that project).

### Longer answer

When you install a bundle with `bundle --binstubs`, Bundler will install all your bundle-specific binstubs into the `bin/` subdirectory (relative to the Gemfile), rather than putting them into the gemset's global binstub paths.

You would typically do this to:

1. Ensure that the `rails` binstub you're running is the one in your Gemfile (as opposed to a different version that got installed into your gemset later, separate from Bundler), and
2. To improve execution time (since it's functionally equivalent to `bundle exec rails` except minus one subprocess invocation).

### Global binstubs vs Bundler binstubs

If you type `which rails`, you will get a long path like `/usr/local/rvm/gems/jruby-1.7.18/bin/rails`, and the contents of which: `` cat `which  rails` ``

```
#!/usr/bin/env jruby_executable_hooks
#
# This file was generated by RubyGems.
#
# The application 'railties' is installed as part of a gem, and
# this file is here to facilitate running it.
#

require 'rubygems'

version = ">= 0"

if ARGV.first
  str = ARGV.first
  str = str.dup.force_encoding("BINARY") if str.respond_to? :force_encoding
  if str =~ /\A_(.*)_\z/
    version = $1
    ARGV.shift
  end
end

gem 'railties', version
load Gem.bin_path('railties', 'rails', version)
```

After running `bundler --binstubs`, if you `cat bin/rails`, you'll get something like:

```
#!/usr/bin/env jruby
#
# This file was generated by Bundler.
#
# The application 'rails' is installed as part of a gem, and
# this file is here to facilitate running it.
#

require 'pathname'
ENV['BUNDLE_GEMFILE'] ||= File.expand_path("../../Gemfile",
  Pathname.new(__FILE__).realpath)

require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler/setup'

load Gem.bin_path('railties', 'rails')
```

The key difference there is that the `bin/` version sets the `BUNDLE_GEMFILE` environment variable, and it requires `bundler/setup`, which is what tells Bundler to go do its thing with gem paths. The `bin/rails` script is bundler-aware, and is aware of your Gemfile, so it can prepare your environment right off the bat.

I generally recommend using `--binstubs` and `bin/x` invocations over the gemset versions.

Answer (score 0):

Consider this scenario:

I had an app that was using Rails version 4.0.0.
My goal was to upgrade it to Rails 4.1.9. To do so, I tried to upgrade it step by step: first, upgrading to 4.0.13, then 4.1 and finally 4.1.9.

Everything went smoothly. All the tests were passing using RSpec.

Finally, I tried to run my server with `rails s`. Booom! Ruby crashed.
Then, I used `bin/rails s`. Everything went ok.

So I think if you have different version of rails set up in your system, it's safer to use `bin/rails` option.

P.S. To make sure that my assumption is correct, I removed all rails version except 4.1.9 and then I tried to rerun the server with `rails s`. No crash this time.

Hope this clarifies.

Answer (score -1):

When you run an executable via shell in a unix-based operating system, your system path will be searched first. To see all of the directories in your `$PATH`, try this from your terminal prompt:

```
echo $PATH
```

the rails executable will be present in one of the listed directories.

**Edit - The text below is completely wrong, my apologies**

Optionally, from the root of your rails directory, you can run the executable in the bin directory. To do this, that is, to ensure you're running the local executable and not one found in your `$PATH`, you need a '.' before the command. So,

`./bin/rails`

not

`bin/rails`

Comment: This is wrong. The shell only resolves executables on the `$PATH` **only** if it contains no slashes. Thus, `bin/rails` will always be evaluated in the current directory and will be totally unaffected from the `$PATH`.